# Returning Previous Quarter and Year Google Sheets

Tags: excel, date, google-sheets, formula

I am having trouble writing a formula in Google sheets that will return the previous quarter based on today's date.

For example, if I have cell A1 as =today() which is 1/26/22, I would like cell B1 to return the previous quarter "Q4 2021".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have tagged "Excel"; but your description and another tag list "Google Sheets." These are two entirely different platforms. Please confirm which you are using by removing the tag that does not apply. In addition, do you actually need to do this for *one and only one cell* (i.e., A1)? Or are you doing to need a return for every cell in a range? If the latter, is the starting cell of that range actually A1, or is it some other cell? And does the range to process run down a column or across a row?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't hear back from you on my comment to your original post. But assuming that you are, in fact, using Google Sheets and that you are actually only needing the return for one cell (A1), this should work in B1:

`=VLOOKUP(MONTH(A1),{1,"Q4";4,"Q1";7,"Q2";10,"Q3"},2,TRUE)&" "&YEAR(A1)-IF(MONTH(A1)<4,1,0)`

If you were trying to get such a return for an entire columnar range (say, A2:A with a heading in A1), you could use this version in B1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Prev. Quarter"; IF(A2:A="",,VLOOKUP(MONTH(A2:A),{1,"Q4";4,"Q1";7,"Q2";10,"Q3"},2,TRUE)&" "&YEAR(A2:A)-IF(MONTH(A2:A)<4,1,0))})`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go... just copy and paste this formula in `B1`:

```
=IFS(
    A1="","",
    AND(MONTH(A1)>=1,MONTH(A1)<=3),"Q4 "&YEAR(A1)-1,
    AND(MONTH(A1)>=4,MONTH(A1)<=6),"Q1 "&YEAR(A1),
    AND(MONTH(A1)>=7,MONTH(A1)<=9),"Q2 "&YEAR(A1),
    AND(MONTH(A1)>=10,MONTH(A1)<=12),"Q3 "&YEAR(A1)
)
```